# Common elements from BSTs

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working with BSTs and i'm asked to get the common elements in 2 BST and insert them to a 3rd one. My method should  return the 3rd BST. I've done the same thing when working with LL, but now for the BST, I don't know where to start! I've came  up with a solution, but the thing is it's working with the roots of the tree and it doesn't seem right to me. I'm so lost, I can't find the starting point. Advice is much appreciated.

EDIT: I've created the method in the BST class

```
 public BinarySearchTree common(BinarySearchTree t1,BinarySearchTree t2){
    return commonValues(t1.root,t2.root);
}


private BinarySearchTree commonValues(BinaryTreeNode node1, BinaryTreeNode node2) {
    //  BinaryTreeNode temp1;
    //  BinaryTreeNode temp2;
    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

    if (node1 == null && node2 == null) {
        System.out.println("Empty trees!");
    } else {
        if (node1.getInfo().equals(node2.getInfo())) {
            tree.insert(node1.getInfo());
        } else if (node1.getInfo().compareTo(node2.getInfo()) > 0) { // go left
            node1 = node1.getLlink();
            commonValues(node1, node2);
        } else {
            node2 = node2.getRlink();
            commonValues(node1, node2);
              }
       }
       return tree;
   }
```

I'm having a NullPointerException every time I run it though

Comment: Are there any restrictions, why not flatten the BSTs into in-order list then compare the lists for common elements and add them to the 3rd BST?

Comment: whenever I run the code, it prints the address of the tree, and sometimes it prints the insert method's exception " No duplicates"

Comment: @gtgaxiola the BSTs are already in order when the method is called

Comment: Do t1 and t2 change during the loops? If that's not the case (I consider that likely), how could the algorithm possibly be correct?

Comment: @fabian the elements in t1 and t2 are generated randomly

Comment: @Sara: Regardless of how the elements are created you have to traverse the trees somehow. Your code only seems to search the roots of the trees in the other tree.

Comment: @fabian that's what i thought, but I can't seem to find a way to traverse the trees, like when to go left and right after checking the roots

Comment: @Sara: If you do an inorder-traversal (which gives you the element in sorted order) of the tree, you only have to keep track of the last element visited to decide for each relevant node, if you have traversed the left, right or both subtrees. Parent pointers in the nodes or a `Stack` might be helpful for the path to the root node (if you don't want to use a recursive approach, restricting the depth of the tree to the maximum stack size of java).

Comment: @fabian I'm supposed to work with BST only though

Answer (score 1):

Your loop control variables seems to be doing nothing. Basically it seems like executing the same statements based on the size of the two trees.

Not sure on the BinarySearchTree implementation, but here is what I think is workable:

We want to create a new BST using common elements. To find the common elements:

1. The new tree (T3) will only be as big as the smaller of the (T1, T2)
2. Compare the size of T1 and T2
3. Use the smaller one to search against the bigger tree. Traverse in
   pre-order manner. For each node, if search returns true, make an
   insert into the T3

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what is the interface of BinarySearchTree, but i will suggest some ideas.

The first is that you need to go over the tree, because if you always check root you are doing nothing. You could have a method that give you the next node in a certain orden, [pre-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for example (`t2Iterator.next()` in the following example).

And the second thing is that you do not need go over the two tree for insert the common elements, one time is enought: if you make the second loop you are inserting the same elements that in the first loop.

This is, in code, what i am trying to say you.

```
public static BinarySearchTree common(BinarySearchTree t1, BinarySearchTree t2) {

    BinarySearchTree t3 = new BinarySearchTree();
    BinarySearchTree t2Iterator = t2;

    for (int x = 0; x < t2.size(); x++) {
        if (t1.search(t2Iterator.root.getInfo())) {
            t3.insert(t2Iterator.root.getInfo());
        } 
        t2Iterator = t2Iterator.next();
    }

    return t3;
}
```

And this is how could be the function next with pre order traverse

```
BinarySearchTree next() {
    if (leftChild != null) {
        return leftChild;
    }
    else if (rightChild != null) {
        return rightChild;
    }
    else {
        BinarySearchTree iterator = this;
        while (iterator.parent != null) {
            if (iterator.parent.rightChild != null) {
                return iterator.parent.rightChild;
            }

            iterator = iterator.parent;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what I had in mind for the problem, because I'm calling the root of each tree, the left/right subtrees aren't being traversed, but I assumed they were going to be traversed by the search method because the search method traverse both parts of the tree

Comment: also, to make things clear @Narkha the BinarySearchTree is inherited from a class " BinaryTree" that has the treeNode as protected class

Comment: then how could you traverse the tree?

Comment: thats what i've been trying to figure out, only thing confusing me is when to traverse the left side of the tree and when to traverse the right side

Comment: I'm really confuse don what to fix first at the moment, so the problem lies in using the roots because t1.root.getinfo() only gets the roots and that's apparently why there are duplicates in the 3rd tree

Comment: Puede haber duplicados por dos razones: la primera es que si t1.root está en t2, insertará t1.root en t3 t2.size() veces por el primer bucle; la segunda es que si t2.root está en t1, insertará t2.root t1.size() veces por el segundo bucle.

Comment: upss, yes is, spanish

Comment: funny i don't speak Spanish

Comment: but if t1.root is in t2 then I'm inserting it in t3

Comment: There may be duplicates for two reasons: the first is that if t1.root is in t2, t1.root will be inserted t2.size() times in t3 in the first loop; the second is that if t2.root is in t1, t2.root will be inserted t1.size() times in t3 in the second loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45496/discussion-between-narkha-and-sara)

Comment: in the line where you initialize the iterator, how can you make a BST point to a BinaryTreeNode object? that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Your task is similar to "merging two trees" with exception that you only put common elements to the output tree. So basically it can be done in linear time by following this steps:

1. Start with iterators at the smallest elements of both trees.
  2.

> ```
> while both iterators are inside trees:
> if (TreeA.node(iteratorA).value > TreeB.node(iteratorB).value) 
>    iteratorB = nextNodeinB();
> else if (TreeA.node(iteratorA).value < TreeB.node(iteratorB).value)
>    iterator A = nextNodeInA();
> else
>    outputTree.add(new node(TreeA.node(iteratorA).value)); //the values are equal, so add to the output tree.
> ```
>
> 3. If iterator of one of the trees is out of its tree, check through the rest of elements in the other tree if any of them is equal to the last element of the already-finished tree.

So you go through both trees inOrder, from the smallest to the largest element and if you find elements in both trees with the same value you create a node in the output tree with that common value.